# How to convert discord webhook embeds to a dictionary of its values?

Tags: c#, dictionary, discord, webhooks

So im trying to create a discord bot in c# and i currently need to extract the values of a incoming Webhook embed and convert them into a dictionary.

What would be the best way to do this?

Not tried much yet im relatively new to discord bots so im mainly just looking for a rough direction where i should start

Comment: Can you provide a code sample what you already tried and what your exact issues are? 
As far as i understand you want an object list converted to a dictionary?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.